# Finding if Any date in a table is between 2 dates

Tags: sql, between, days

I have a SQL query where I need to find out if any date in a table relating to a specific client is between another date in a different table and that date plus 5 days

I have a table with a list of client details (client table) with the fields clients name, address and ID (PK) in it

I have a table with the annual assessments details where we review the clients account (assessment table) with the fields  assessment date and assessment ID (pk) in it

I a separate table with a list of the dates we have spoken with the client (meeting table) with the fields Meeting name (eg meeting type 1, meeting type 2, meeting type 3) meeting date, meeting ID (PK)

We can see the clients a lot of times during the year for different meetings, however I need a query that will tell me Yes or No, has the client been spoken to with 5 days of the annual assessment.

So I need something like the below

```sql
Select 
        Client_ID (PK) (from client table)
       ,Client_Name (from client table)
       ,Assessment_ID (PK) from assessment table
       ,Assessment_date (from assessment table)
```

Then here I need something here that will say, CASE WHEN from all of the dates in the meetings table relating to this client, are any of them within 5 days of the assessment date if so 'Y' if not 'N'

I'm fine with joining all the relevant table as and when required it's just the query for any date in the meeting table between assessment date and assessment date + 5 that I am struggling with.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: What software are you using? Sql Server? MySQL? Date functions vary widely between implementations. Also, can you provide a basic breakdown of the assessment and meeting table schemas?

Answer (score 0):

it's interesting to pay attention to some points:

- If the Customers table has a relationship with the evaluation table, if so you can make an **inner join** between the two, finding what evaluations have for an X customer.
- If you already have this relationship now, do an **inner join, Exists or IN** to validate if Client X exists in the Meeting table.
- If it is not possible to make this relationship by PK, it is a problem regarding the structure of the data, since without reference to the customer in the meeting table, I did not find a way to make this relationship in your text.
- Assuming you've done everything I mentioned above just make a **CASE** for your code

for example:

[image]

Note: I didn't quite understand the filter point related to the dates of the two tables, so I left the WHERE like this,

Graciously.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
SELECT  CustomerData
        ,CASE
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MeetingDate, GETDATE()) < 5 THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
         END AS CustomerConsultedLastFiveDays
FROM    CustomerMeetingTable
WHERE   Conditions = Conditions;
```